# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' (n-body-problem)

Tags: python, integer, append, attributeerror

Im trying to write a programm for the n-body-problem as my seminar work. I tried to append but it didnt work. Than i learned over stackoverflow that i cant append an integer. I tried out a lot of things that where allready asked and answered related to this topic (such as using insert instead of append), but it didnt work. Im pretty new to programming so this has probably an easy solution, but i really cant figure it out.

```py
Bodies = 25

Bodies.append(Body(1000, 350, 350, [0,0]))

for i in range(0, Bodies):
        Bodies.append(Body(random.randrange(10, 500), random.randrange(50, 650), random.randrange(50, 650), [(random.randrange(-10,10)/20), (random.randrange(-10,10)/20)]))
```

Comment: `append` is a function of a `list`. Did you mean to create a list?

Comment: yes. I can put in the rest of the code if that helps answering my question

Comment: You need to write ``Bodies =[25]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Bodies as both a list and integer. It looks like you need to do something like this.

```
Bodies = []
numBodies = 25
for i in range(numBodies):
    # Insert rest of code
```